# Find all polynomials with integer coefficients f such that for all $n > 2005$ the number $f(n)$ is a divisor of $n^{n−1} −1$.

Tags: functions, polynomials

This particular question is about this problem posted on AoPS.

It says:

> Find all polynomials with integer coefficients f such that for all $n > 2005$ the number $f(n)$ is a divisor of $n^{n−1} −1$.

My solution to this problem is:
$$f(x) = x - 1\text{ or } f(x) = 1\text{ or } f(x) = -1$$ 
Because:

$$n^{n−1} −1 = (n-1)(n^{n-2} + n^{n−3}+ \dots+ 1)$$
So the only factors for $n^{n−1} −1$ are $n - 1$ and $ ±1$(because $n^{n-2} + n^{n−3}+ \dots+ 1$ can not factorized for $n >0$). Hence, my solution would be $f(x) = x -1$, or $±1$.  However, I didn't found the solution on AoPS very helpful: it says ${(x-1)}^2$ is also a solution. Can some one elaborate more? Thanks.

PS: If you want the solution at AoPS, Here you go:

> http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?t=21897

Comment: What do you mean by "$n^{n-2} + n^{n-3} + \ldots + 1$ can not be factorized for $n > 0$"?  It's certainly not always prime.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, For n always greater than zero, the function doesn't have a zero ? Does it ? Based on the solution on AoPS, it is divisible by $n-1$ right ? And I don't see why that is true.

Comment: This is not a polynomial.  Being divisible by $n-1$ (as an integer, for positive integer $n$) is not the same thing as having a zero at $n=1$.

Comment: $n \equiv 1 \mod n-1$.  $n^{n-2}+n^{n-3}+\ldots+1$, i.e. $\sum_{j=0}^{n-2} n^j$, is the sum of $n-1$ terms each $\equiv 1 \mod n-1$, therefore $\equiv n-1 \equiv 0 \mod n-1$.

Comment: Thanks, I kinda get an idea